# set Timer is not working in void loop() arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have the following piece of code which I was able to test and verify that it works properly.

In essence, the call `myThread.setInterval(5000);` makes the **led** start blinking after *5 seconds*.

```c++
#include <Thread.h>

Thread myThread = Thread();
char powerValue;
int ledPin1 = 2;
boolean flag = false;

void myThreadCallback() {
    digitalWrite(ledPin1, HIGH);
}

void setup() {
    pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(ledPin1, LOW);
    Serial.begin(9600);

    myThread.onRun(myThreadCallback);
    flag =  true;
    myThread.setInterval(5000);
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()) {
        powerValue = Serial.read();
        Serial.println(powerValue);
    }

    if (powerValue == 'A' ) {

    } else if (powerValue == 'a' ) {
        digitalWrite(ledPin1, LOW);
    }

    if (myThread.shouldRun() && flag == true)
        myThread.run();

    powerValue = 'Z';
}
```

I wrote a slight variation of this code which pushes *that call* into the *loop()* code, which is shown below.

However, for some reasons that are unknown to me, with this code the **led** lights up right from the start instead of waiting *5 seconds*.

```c++
#include <Thread.h>

Thread myThread = Thread();
char powerValue;
int ledPin1 = 2;
boolean flag = false;

void myThreadCallback() {
    digitalWrite(ledPin1, HIGH);
}

void setup() {
    pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(ledPin1, LOW);
    Serial.begin(9600);

    myThread.onRun(myThreadCallback);
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()) {
        powerValue = Serial.read();
        Serial.println(powerValue);
    }

    if (powerValue == 'A' ) {
        flag =  true;
        myThread.setInterval(5000);
        // checks if thread should run
    } else if (powerValue == 'a' ) {
        digitalWrite(ledPin1, LOW);
    }

    if (myThread.shouldRun() && flag == true)
        myThread.run();

    powerValue = 'Z';
}
```

**Question.** Could anyone help me understand why the behaviour is different among the two sources?

Answer (score 0):

In your modified code, in the loop, the if condition is not satisfied initially, so the setInterval is not called and it runs immediately.